# Return 404 for any Wordpress's feed/rss

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to force return 404 if url matches `"feed"`: `http://example.com/wordpress/?feed=rss2`

I added `RedirectMatch ^(.*)feed(.*)$ [R=404]` to .htacess but it doesn't return any 404 error.

For Wordpress in functions.php I can use next code:

```
function fb_disable_feed() {
    include( get_query_template( '404' ) );
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit; 
}
add_action('do_feed', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
```

But it redirects `http://example.com/wordpress/?feed=rss2` (301) to `http://example.com/wordpress/feed` and only then it returns 404 error.

I need that `http://example.com/wordpress/?feed=rss2` would return 404 error & not redirect to `http://example.com/wordpress/feed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using WP PHP code you can do this via mod_rewrite rule.

Place this rule **as first rule** in your main WP .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} feed [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```